# WebDriver open rich:popupPanel

Tags: webdriver, htmlunit, showmodaldialog

We are testing an application with Selenium WebDriver. HTMLUnitDriver is our choice (because of non-gui-testing) and sometimes IEDriver for Presentationpurposes. Anyway, i try to perform a click on a button, this one has to open an rich:popuPanel(modal=true) and click a Link on that Panel. With IEDriver that's no problem, but with HTMLUnitDriver the popupPanel doesn't open. I tried to perform these clicks in several ways:

```
    JavascriptExecutor jsdriver = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    jsdriver.executeScript("$('input[id$=freigabeCmd_id]').focus();");
    //below are the other tries
    // jsdriver.executeScript("$('input[id$=freigabeCmd_id]').click();");
    // jsdriver.executeScript("window.document.getElementById('editorViewForm_id:freigabeCmd_id').click()");
    // jsdriver.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", freigabeButton);
    // jsdriver.executeScript("arguments[0].fireEvent('onclick');", freigabeButton);
```

further i tried it the "normal way":

```
        freigabeButton.click();
    //below are other ways i found here on stackoverflow
    // freigabeButton.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    // new Actions(driver).moveToElement(freigabeButton).clickAndHold().release().build().perform();
```

but nothing brought me to get the popupPanel "visible". Anyone got an idea why?! i'm really stuck right now. If you need more Informations pls let me know.

using: HTMLUnit Version 2.12 and latest SeleniumVersion

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your webapp uses javascript to launch the rich pop-up panel, and you are running HtmlUnitDriver with javascript disabled? It is [disabled by default](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver), so you need to explicitly enable it.

Comment: Javascript is enabled. client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);